# How to delete events from Full Calendar?

Tags: javascript

I'm using [FullCalendar](https://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) module

I have added an event. Now I want to delete it. How can I remove/delete an event from the calendar?

Comment: Do you want to delete event from the site or from calender?

Comment: The fullcalendar module is a views plugin that display's certain content types. Clicking the calendar item should take you to the node, and then you can edit and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to be able to delete nodes directly from the calendar, here is how:

make sure you have the tokens module installed/enabled.

1. in your fullcalendar view, add the Content:Nid field.
2. add a global:custom text field that is under the nid field you just added, and input the following as the text:

   node/[nid]/delete
3. click on the fullcalendar settings (under the format heading) and click "customize fields" click the "use a custom redirect URL" checkbox, then in the dropdown, select your custom text field you created in step 2.
4. save the view.

now when you click on the event, it will ask you to confirm or cancel the deletion of the node.